# Problem with uploading files to LAMP server

Tags: lamp

I have installed LAMP server using such command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-mod-php5 php5 mysql-server phpmyadmin
```

I opened localhost and it said 'It Works!'.

I also opened localhost/phpmyadmin and it says 404...

Anyway its not the biggest problem. The biggest one is that I cant even upload files to it. I go to System Files -> var -> www. I see here index.html. I can only read it (readonly) and can't save it to apply changes. I cant even add any files to www folder!

When I try to (open Text Editor, write some script and save it in www folder) it gives me an error (something that I cant save files in this directory).

Please help me solving this problem. Im trying to for few days I have reinstalled whole Ubuntu few times, and still nothing.. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. 
for localhost/phpmyadmin, try created a symbolic link named phpmyadmin in /var/www

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

when your phpmyadmin folder is located in /usr/share/ that work in most problem with 404 page, but if that not working try this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=841173&page=2)

then for your problem about folder var/www ..
are you doing that as root or user? because /var folder can only access with root permission..

```
sudo -i
```

can switch you to root,when change like this..

```
root@comp:/home/user#
```

then you can edit with text editor like gedit or geany

```
geany var/www/info.php
```

with this you can edit and save, if you want to add file to var/www try this (from a root shell)

```
nautilus
```

if you want know more or want edit all folder and file without root try this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1210285&page=2)

i hope that help

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues but successfully solved them.Check this tutorial:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1233096)